# Do we integrate electric potential when solving for it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, work

Below I have attached the equation of integrated electric potential. I am confused because through previous practice problems I did, I did not integrate for electric potential or used the dot product. I simply used the equation $V=Es$ or $V=U/q$ and plugged the values in. When do I have to integrate?

$$\Delta V=V_f-V_i
=-\int_{s_i}^{s_f}E_s ds
=-\int_{i}^{f}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use integration if the electric field
varies from place to place.
Only when $\vec{E}$ is a constant then you can simplify by
$$\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}=\vec{E}\cdot\int d\vec{s}
=\vec{E}\cdot \Delta\vec{s}$$

You need to use the the dot product $\vec{E}\cdot\ d\vec{s}$
when the two vectors don't have the same direction.
Only when they have the same direction then you can simplify
by $$\vec{E}\cdot\ d\vec{s}=E\ ds$$

Comment: So for point charges would I need to integrate it since the E field gets weaker far away? But the end result of integrating it and just using Es is the same

Comment: @Muse Yes, for calculating the potential $V$ around a point charge you need to integrate $E$. But I don't see how this would give the same result as $V=Es$.

Comment: Because it was just be E(sf)-E(is) which would be the same as the non integrated one E(change in s)